# Cannot open backup device Error

Tags: sql-server, security, backup

I have a SQL Server Agent job that backs up a database on a remote server to a network drive. Linked Server, I believe is set up correctly but I get the following error:

> Msg 3013, Sev 16, State 1, Line 35
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000]
>
> Msg 3201, Sev 16, State 1, Line 35
>   Cannot open backup device. Operating system error 1326
>   (failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 1815). [SQLSTATE 42000]

I have used SQL Server Configuration Manager to change the Log On to "This Account", selected the domain account and supplied the right password.

Then, on the Linked Server Properties, I mapped the Local Login to the domain account and ticked "Impersonate" The security on the network drive folder is set to "everyone" and full permission is given. And yet still getting this error and cannot backup the database as a result.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

So in Configuration Manager, you configured the SQL Agent service account, correct?  That is the account that will execute SQL Agent jobs, by default.

This query will verify your settings:

```
SELECT servicename, service_account
FROM   sys.dm_server_services
go
```

Do you get the error when executing the job via a schedule, when executing manually, or both?

If you are using T-SQL commands to perform the backup, what happens when you paste the commands into a query window and manually execute?  Can you reproduce the error there as well?

Answer (score 1):

dLight, the issue may have nothing to do with Linked Server.

This is most likely a syntax error. Within your BACKUP DATABASE command, you may be using a reserved keyword somewhere, or maybe an extra comma, parentheses or apostrophe.

What I'd suggest is : parse the BACKUP DATABASE command in your editor and look for any error messages. Or you can post it here so that we can have a look at it.